# Find the inverse function of $ f (x ) = x^2 - x - 2$

Tags: functions, inverse

Find the inverse function of $ f (x ) = x^2 - x - 2$, where x is equal to or larger than  1/2.

I tried to express it in form of $ (x - 1 )^2 = y + 2 $, but this is not true as the term in the middle is $ x $ and not $ 2x $.

Can anybody show me the full work solution?

Comment: Wrong completion of the square: $x^2-x-2=y$ $\not\Rightarrow$ $(x-1)^2=y+2$. Do it carefully.

Comment: Yes, I know it... I have stated in question above

Comment: @A.P. It is ok for the interval $x\ge 1/2$.

Comment: @A.G. Ah, of course. I missed that part of the statement.

Comment: OP: Why do you ask for "the full work solution"?

Comment: As it is easier to understand if do like that, but  explaining the concept is also enough for me to understand it

Answer (score 6):

Recall that $(x+a)^2 = x^2 +2ax +a^2$. Hence $x^2-x = x^2 -2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}x = \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 -\frac{1}{4}$. Therefore
$x^2-x-2=\left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 -\frac{1}{4} -2$. Can you conclude from here?